# socket.io-client connects with localhost but not with IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am struggling to find out the problem with connecting to server.
With `localhost`, it's working fine, but when I am changing the host to `IP` address, it throws an error and what's strange for me, it adds `/socket.io` as a pathname.

```
'ws://134.122.32.44:8290/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket'
```

> "socket.io-client": "^4.3.2",
> "socket.io": "^4.4.1",

This is a server config part.

```
 const { Server } = require("socket.io");
 this.socket = new Server(port, {
        cors: {
            origin: '*'
        }
    });
```

And this is the client config

```
this.socket = io(`ws://${wsHost}:${wsPort}`, {
  timeout: 15000,
  withCredentials: true,
  reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
});
```

If wsHost is `localhost` it is working fine, but not with an actual IP address.
I am new to sockets and just want to find out where do I need to find the issue.
Is it related to backend configs or client ?

**UPDATED**

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
 this.socket = new Server(port, {
        cors: {
            origin: '*'
        },
        path: "/api",
    });
```

And in client also.

```
this.socket = io(`ws://${wsHost}:${wsPort}`, {
  timeout: 15000,
  path: "/api",
  withCredentials: true,
  reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
});
```

Here is the Nginx server configs

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error.log debug;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://134.122.32.44:7878;
    }
    location /var/www/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://134.122.32.44:8290;
    }
}
```

Error is here

```
websocket.js:50 WebSocket connection to 'ws://134.122.32.44:8290/api/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

Comment: Are you connecting to a secure connection ?  EG..  wss://  not ws://

Comment: the path is added by default (by socket io) do you have this code on  your local machine or a server? (for example if its nginx you need to add reverse proxy configuration)

Comment: I have added `path: '/api',` in Server socket config.But it doesn't work again.Localhost is working but not with IP.The server is deployed but I am connecting it through local environment.

Comment: @Keith For this moment it's only `ws://`

Comment: See updated version please.I have added Nginx configs as well

Comment: `it throws an error`, it might help others if you show us the error too.

Comment: It just can't connect.Although I posted the error at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Is that the full error, there is usually some extra details after `failed:`